# Pattern matching a List of Strings with a String using isInfixOf

Tags: haskell

Hello i am a beginner in haskell and i have a problem with comparing/matching Strings from a set List with a given String as Parameter.

What i want to achieve is:

I have a set List

```
colorTypes = ["red" , "blue" ,"yellow" , "green" ]
```

what i want to do is make a Function to compare each element of the List with a given String using the isInfixOf Function from Data.List and depending on the outcome from isInfixOf return a Pattern

Example if i use the function:

```
getColorData colorTypes "red"
```

it should return

```
[1, 0, 0, 0]
```

What i have tried is:

```
import Data.List 

getColorData  :: [String] -> String -> [Int]
getColorData (g:h:j:k) str 
    | isInfixOf g str = [1, 0, 0, 0]
    | isInfixOf h str = [0, 1, 0, 0]
    | isInfixOf j str = [0, 0, 1, 0]
    | isInfixOf k str = [0, 0, 0, 1]
    | otherwise = []
```

i get the error : Parse error in pattern: isInfixOf with this function

i also tried this with case

```
 getColorData  :: [String] -> String -> [Int]
 getColorData (g:h:j:k) str = case (g:h:j:k) of
                         isInfixOf g str -> [1, 0, 0, 0]
                         isInfixOf h str -> [0, 1, 0, 0]
                         isInfixOf j str -> [0, 0, 1, 0]
                         isInfixOf k str -> [0, 0, 0, 1]
```

this also doesnt work and i get the Couldn't match type error.

I don't know if my approach is wrong or if there are any other ways to get what i want but i appreciate any help

Comment: Well `k` is *not* the last item, but the *remaining items*.

Comment: Now i see my mistake, i have to add [] so that it would be `code (g:h:j:k:[]) `

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I think you're doing it wrong. I'd almost certainly write ```getColorData color colors = map (color `isInfixOf`) colors```. Easy to read and idiomatic, and uses a more sensible type than `Int`. You might also be interested in [`filter`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter) or [`findIndices`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:findIndices), depending on exactly what you're doing.

Comment: @Daniel Wagner 
The problem with that function is that u are mapping the color String with isInfixOf to the List but i want to use isInfixOf on every element of the list with color String. It should be possible to use ur function with recursion maybe  Still thank you for your answer.

Something like this but the function is still missing something : 
`getColorData (x:xs) color = map (x 'isInfixOf' ) color` and somewhere to use this part  `getColorData xs`

Comment: @Ninexreaker Have you tried running my proposed function? I think you'll be pleasantly surprised. It already does "use `isInfixOf` on every element of the list" -- that is what `map` does. e.g. `getColorData "red" ["fred", "green", "bluered", "blue"]` returns `[True, False, True, False]`, and `getColorData "red" ["red","blue","yellow","green"]` returns `[True,False,False,False]` just as required by your example input/output pair.

Comment: Yes you are right. It was my mistake using a bad example on my original post. I should have used something like "redxy" as the String to compare on because then it doesnt work anymore. But thank you anyways, its always good to get more opinions!

Comment: @Ninexreaker Still not really a problem, just swap the order of arguments to `isInfixOf`, as in ```getColorData color colors = map (`isInfixOf` color) colors```.

Comment: @Daniel Wagner Yes i tried your new function with following example: `getColorData "redxyz" ["red" , "blue" ,"yellow" , "green" ]` and now it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here that you pattern match with:

```
getColorData (g:h:j:k) str
```

Here `g`, `h`, and `j` are the *heads* (first elements) of the list, but `k` is the *tail* of the list (the remaining items). So `k` has as type `[String]`, *not* `String`.

We can fix it by using `[g,h,j,k]` which is a list of four elements:

```
getColorData  :: [String] -> String -> [Int]
getColorData [g,h,j,k] str 
    | isInfixOf g str = [1, 0, 0, 0]
    | isInfixOf h str = [0, 1, 0, 0]
    | isInfixOf j str = [0, 0, 1, 0]
    | isInfixOf k str = [0, 0, 0, 1]
    | otherwise = []
```

But still it is not really good design. Since for lists with less, or more than four elements, this function will error. I'm also not sure whether using an `isInfixOf` condition is a good idea at all: it means that the order of the list can sometimes determine what the result will be: a list where two elements are swapped might result in a different. Finally the code is very repetitive (not following the **D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself principle).

A more elegant version could be:

```
getColorData :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Maybe [Int]
getColorData [] _ = Nothing
getColorData (x:xs) s | isInfixOf x s = Just (1: map (const 0) xs)
                      | otherwise = fmap (0:) (getColorData xs s)
```

Here we let it work for any type `a` where two `a`s have an equality relation. Furthermore it works with lists of all lengths. It returns `Nothing` if the elements can not be found, and `Just e` with `e` an entity vector with the length of the list as the number of dimensions.

Comment: I forgot that using () would result the remaining of list on the last element. Now i can see why it did not work. Thank you for that!